# WCF application don't working in my home network

Tags: wcf

i create a small wcf apps when i am testing this apps in my machine then it is working but when i run the wcf server end on another pc at my home in same network then i am getting error
**A remote side security requirement was not fulfilled during authentication.Try increasing the ProtectionLevel and/or ImpersonationLevel.**

both the pc at my home in same work group and they can access each other. i try to find out the answer but people say this is firewall issue. so i disable firewall at both the pc but still getting the problem. here is my sample code. please guide me how can i run this wcf apps in two pc at my home network. thanks

### Service end

```
namespace WCFSample
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string MyName(string name);
}
}

namespace WCFSample
{
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string MyName(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("My Name... {0}", name);
    }

}
}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static ServiceHost customerHost = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            HostCustomerService();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the services.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

            catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);    
        }
        finally
        {
            customerHost.Close();
        }

    }

    private static void HostCustomerService()
    {
        customerHost = new ServiceHost(typeof
            (Service1));

        ServiceEndpoint tcpEndpoint = customerHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(IService1), new NetTcpBinding(),
            "net.tcp://192.168.1.103:9020/Service1");

        customerHost.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", tcpEndpoint.Address, tcpEndpoint.Name);
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
   }
  }
```

### client end

```
namespace Client1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IService1 channel = null;

        var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(
             "net.tcp://192.168.1.103:9020/Service1");
       channel  = ChannelFactory<IService1>.CreateChannel(new NetTcpBinding(), endPoint);
       Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
       string line = Console.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine(channel.MyName(line));
       Console.ReadKey();
    }

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by default, NetTcpBinding requires a secure channel.

When you create your binding (on client and server), instead of:

`new NetTcpBinding()`

Try:

`new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None)`

Comment: yes this work. the code as follows.             var myBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            ServiceHost duplex = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServerWCallbackImpl));
            duplex.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServerWithCallback),
                myBinding,
                "net.tcp://192.168.1.2:9080/DataService");
            duplex.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Host is running, press <ENTER> to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            duplex.Close();

Comment: please tell me onething that how to off the security when we use app.config at client side & web.config at server side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097331/securitymode-none-leads-to-timeoutexception-instead-of-communicationobjectfaulte

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412111/multiple-instances-of-a-self-hosted-wcf-service

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/271b1816-173c-4c76-a4c4-fd9fda4b5e91/